# Connected but no value send, aedes tls and mqtt.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt, aedes

1/Producing error:

-File broker.js :

```
const fs = require('fs')
const aedes = require('aedes')()
const port = 8883    
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/crt.pem')
}    
const server = require('tls').createServer(options, aedes.handle)    
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('MQTT broker server started and listening on port ', port)
})
```

-File sub.js :

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
const fs = require('fs');
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("cert/ca.ca");
//if using client certificates
var KEY = fs.readFileSync('cert/key.pem');
var CERT = fs.readFileSync('cert/crt.pem');
var options={
  clientId:"mqttjs01",
  //port:8883,
  //host:'192.168.1.71',
  //protocol:'mqtts',
  rejectUnauthorized : false,
  ca:caFile,
  key: KEY,
  cert: CERT
}
var client  = mqtt.connect("mqtts://domain.com:8883",options);    
//console.log("connected flag  " + client.connected);    
client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected');
  client.subscribe('message')
})
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    context = message.toString();
    console.log("sub:",topic+'-'+context)
})
```

-File pub.js :

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
const fs = require('fs');
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("cert/ca.ca");
//if using client certificates
var KEY = fs.readFileSync('cert/key.pem');
var CERT = fs.readFileSync('cert/crt.pem');
var options={
  clientId:"mqttjs01",
  //port:8883,
  //host:'192.168.1.71',
  //protocol:'mqtts',
  rejectUnauthorized : false,
  ca:caFile,
  key: KEY,
  cert: CERT
}
var client  = mqtt.connect("mqtts://domain.com:8883",options);

//console.log("connected flag  " + client.connected);
var dem =0;
client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected');    
    setInterval(function() {
        client.publish('message', 'Hello mqtt ' + dem);
        console.log('Message Sent ' + dem);
        dem = dem + 1;
    }, 5000);
});
```

2/ Error status:

- File broker.js: Run ok `"MQTT broker server started and listening on port 8883"`
- File sub.js: display `"Connected"` but no value show. -> Expect display `"Message Sent ..."` every 5 seconds.
- File pub.js: display `"Connected"` and display `"Message Sent ..."` every chaos seconds.

In the past, I set up done with mosca but when change to aedes, It's not run, do I wrong something ?

Comment: You are using the same client id in both the publisher and the subscriber, this will not work as only one will be able to be connected at the same time.

Comment: Even remove it, it will be the same, I already check it

Comment: Client ids must be different for all clients.

Answer (score 0):

With @hardillb helps, I've fixed it. Thus change clientId in sub and pub, not remove that and value can pass.